# ESP8266 NodeMCU Lua How to clear the heap?

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

How to clear the heap or all memory?
I need to restore state in case script fault.
On fatal errors script stopping and I want to cleanup mess before reset and script fires again.
8266 works as serial port monitor for main processor and memory needed for safe execution of restoration commands.

Comment: Do you want to reset all global variables to the initial state?

Answer (score 0):

Use the command `collectgarbage('collect')` when you need to free used memory.
The standard trigger for collectgarbage in standalone Lua is collecting automatically at 200kb.
You can change the limit to a lower value.
Refer: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#2.5
...and: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-collectgarbage

Example in Lua standalone...

```
$ lua -i
Lua 5.4.3  Copyright (C) 1994-2021 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> gc_example=setmetatable({},{__gc=function(tab) print(tab,'Collected at: ',collectgarbage('count')*1024) end,__name='gc_example'})
> gc_example=empty
> collectgarbage('collect')
gc_example: 0x56626fb0  Collected at:   16918.0 -- resurrect because of __gc metamethod
0
> print(collectgarbage('collect'), collectgarbage('count')*1024) -- freeing
0   16582.0
```